# Char* Array Memory Leak

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having issues de-allocating memory that I used in my `char*` array. In my code snippet below, I am creating a `char*` array named `input` that holds pointers to single words at a time followed by a pointer`NULL` at the end of the array. This is the only time (I believe) I allocate memory in my code.

```
char* input[999];
//exec commands 
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++)
{
    string current = "";
    string word = "";
    int k = 0;
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < commands.at(i).size(); j++) //iterate through letters
    {
        current = commands.at(i);
        //cout << "current: " << current << endl;
        if(current[j] == ' ')
        {
            input[k] = new char[word.size() + 1];
            strcpy(input[k], word.c_str());
            k++;
            word = "";
        }
        else
            word += current[j]; //add letter
        //cout << "word: " << word << endl;
    }
    input[k] = new char[word.size() + 1];
    strcpy(input[k], word.c_str());
    k++;
    input[k] = new char[1]; //add the NULL char *
    input[k] = NULL;
    ...
```

Later on, I attempt to de-allocate this memory with this snippet of code:

```
for(int z = 0; z < k; z++)
{
    delete[] input[z];
}
```

I am iterating through my `char*` array and deleting the memory allocated at each index. Without using this snippet, valgrind informs me of memory leaks. Using this snippet, valgrind informs me of less memory leaks than before.  I am still stuck with the issue of memory still being *definitely lost*.

I am unsure what I am missing to remove the rest of the allocated memory (or if the cause of the rest of the memory leaks is in fact somewhere else in my code). I appreciate any and all help, suggestions, and tips.

Comment: why are you doing this?  `input[k] = new char[1]; //add the NULL char *
    input[k] = NULL;`

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` and `std::string` to take care of all that tedious memory juggling for you?

Comment: I eventually pass this array to `execvp` which takes in `const char *file` and `char *const argv[]` as arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, your problem is in below case,

```
input[k] = new char[1]; //add the NULL char *
input[k] = NULL;
```

here, without `free`-ing `input[k]`, you're assigning `NULL` to it. Thus, the previous `input[k]` is lost.

If you really want `input[k]` to hold `NULL`, (*maybe as a sentinel value*), you can simply do

```
input[k] = NULL;
```

No need to allocate memory separately.

Comment: yep. In case you want to set it to null, you should do `input[k][0] = NULL;`. Or better: `input[k][0] = 0;`

Comment: @gbuzogany IMHO, `input[k] = NULL;` should suffice. `input[k][0]` will be of type `char` which cannot be NULLed.

Comment: I do `k++` right before these lines.  Does the `NULL` not get added to the new index at `k`?

Comment: @masfo001 yeah, it gets added to the new index.

Comment: Sorry. mixed concepts. `input[k] = NULL` is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed most of my memory leaks. I still however have a minimum of 5 bytes lost whenever I run this program, going up the longer `commands.size()` is. Any ideas?

Comment: @masfo001 from this code snippet, I can't find any. But then, i'm not much familiar with C++, maybe someone else will help you out surely. :-)

Comment: can anybody please let me know the reson behind the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new char on where it says `input[k] = new char[1]; //add the NULL char *` Just leave the NULL assignment in and it should work fine.